# How to persist data after application is terminated?

Tags: java, android

I want to persist some edit text data after application is terminated completely. I have two activities `MainActivity1.java` and `MainActivity2.java`.

If user enters data partially and closed the application when he comes back application need to be pick up all the data which he was entered in previous stage.

**Scenario:**

Hence I am using ListView I have map of editText values in the form of key value pair. Currently I am working on `MainActivity2.java` file which has list view. So I am saving the map data in to **Internal Storage** of device when `MainActivity2` is on `onPause()` state. So on `OnResume()` it is showing all data into edit text. 
Now the problem is if I terminate the application completely then it is not picking up the data which I have stored in my **Internal Storage**.

So if I need to store data when application is closed completely which method I need to call.

**Note :** I am using file read and write to store and get data from internal storage

Comment: Are you saving it to internal storage??, Can you please paste the code here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) or [SQLite](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite). Once you do you will basically be saving your values in [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) or [SQLite](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite) in an `onPause() / onDestroy()` method, and then in your `onResume() / onCreate()` methods you will retrieve the previously stored data.

Comment: You can easily manage data by using SharedPreferences or SQLite.

Comment: Thanks Sagar for kind your suggestions.. That worked with Shared Preferences.

Comment: Happy coding...!

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you write any data into the Edittext, you may save it to your **Shared Preference** (if the data value is not much) else you can create a Database using **SQLite** or **Room** (if the set of data is higher).

In both the cases, the data will persist even if you close the application, make sure to save the data after you have input the data in the edit text.

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences -Shared Preference

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite - SQLite

Comment: Ok quite simple.. But do you mean I have to save the data in Shared Preference while entering input into the edittext?? And also where I can see my file If I use Shared Preference??

Comment: You can store the data while in 'onPause()', in this case whenever your application gets into the paused state, the data at that moment will be stored. You can simply get the data by using the get methods of the shared preference. You can both save and retrieve the data from shared preference, refer the link I've attached.

Comment: Thanks Harshit for your support.. I gone through Shared Preference documents and I found that Shared Preference is best option only if our data is small.. But I need to store map of data which is not that huge. So can I use Shared Preference or should I refer SQLite??

Comment: Thanks @Harshit Pathak... for your suggestions. That's  really cool.